# What is cause of spots in image taken with dusty Nikkor AF-S DX 18-200mm ED VR II?

Tags: lens, nikon, cleaning, dx

Dust or pollen inside this lens is common problem so I finally removed the front element and cleaned it, but even after this procedure I have the very same specks in a video as before. So I guess it's the heavily polluted second element - but I'm not sure if I can clean it. 
Someone mentioned that these elements are coated, but I can't find any documentation/evidence. Blower was not enough.

Can I clean it as normal front element lens?

[image: nikkor 18-200mm dust specks]
[image: visible spots in video]

---

EDIT:
So it's the dirty sensor. I set F22 and made video with 18-200mm and 55-300mm and the spots are same.

[image]

Comment: Have you compared against the same camera with no lens attached? Spots that sharp might be more likely to be on the sensor [or covering] itself. You'd be amazed at how much damage the front of a lens can take without significant image degradation - https://wordpress.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/

Comment: I took image/video on 55-300mm and it's 97% better - I mean clean. It's the second element I'm worried about that's causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the front element off, you might as well clean the second element. Treat it with the same care you would the front or rear elements.

**The dark spots in your image are likely caused by marks on the rear element or sensor**, especially when the aperture is stopped down past F11. Small marks and dust on the front and internal elements often do not significantly affect image quality. Even a [hazy element](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104404/75526) can have minimal effect on image quality.

See [What is the effect of a scratched lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/105035/75526)

Comment: Ok it will be sensor, I knew it's not the cleanest, but it was not showing with other lens - the trick with F11+ worked.

Comment: Do you have direct experience with this lens? I mean with cleaning the second element? People were mentioning that 18-300mm has some special coating and should not be touched.

Comment: No direct experience with that lens, but lens coatings are usually pretty resilient. Should be fine if you use lens cleaning solution and clean cloth. Avoid scrubbing. Wear gloves. Fingerprints are worse than dust.